# Passing parameters to Windows Azure Mobile Services script

Tags: parameters, azure-mobile-services

In the newest WAMS sdk update there's a possibility to send parameters using .withparameters in the Query, but this is, so far, only available for the Windows 8 store dll.

How can this be achieved with the WP8 mobile sdk?
I tried to implement the function in the github library, it does compile and all that, but in the SQL Query it doesn't seem to be sent correctly.

So how do you pass parameters to a tables read script? I guess it must be in the Query parameter of the read script, but how?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The support for additional query parameter is coming to the WP8 SDK in the near future. Meanwhile, the way you can do that is with service filters. It’s decidedly not even close to being as user-friendly as the "withParameters", but that could work. The blog post at http://blog.amitapple.com/post/30921523746/customparametersinmobileservices has more details on how to implement this.